# <div></p> causes layout problems

Tags: javascript, html, translation, google-translate

I am trying to translate `<p></p>` content with this method I found online:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head> 
<body class="translate"> 
    <div>Тестирование</p>
    <div class="translate_control" lang="en"></div>

    <script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
      new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
        background: '#f4fa58'
      }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3Wkr/1077/)

As you can see for this to work the translatable text is enclsoed in `<div></p>` which I have never encountered before and it messes up the layout which doesn't happen with just `<p></p>` or `<div></div>`

Can somebody explain what is going on and is there a fix to this?

Comment: Why do you not just close the tags? You cannot close other divs with p's and vice versa

Comment: `<div></p>` isn't well-formed and is obviously causing issues. why not change it to `<div></div>` or `<p></p>`?

Comment: I tried doing that in Fiddle but I couldn't do it without losing the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, `<div></p>` is simply wrong:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head> 
<body class="translate"> 
    <p>Тестирование</p>
    <div class="translate_control" lang="en"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
      new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
        background: '#f4fa58'
      }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
</script>    
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>
</html>
```